# How to add a text with font to an image using jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, imagemagick

I want to add editable text (with font selection) to an image using jquery and want this to be saved as a new image.

Can someone give me some examples or opensource tools for this?

To Explain further, jquery would be used to write text and select font over an image and in the server side PHP can be used to save the new image. I have already developed some server side coding to do the same but looking for a jquery solution for the front end.

Comment: This will not be possible with jQuery/javascript alone as it has no image manipulation or file IO capabilities.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is not possible with javascript alone. I have already created PHP scripts on the server side to save new image. I want Jquery to select position on the image to add text, select font and while saving it needs to send x,y coordinates of the added text for PHP to save that as a new image.

Comment: In that case see Robbie's answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am looking for a non-HTML5 solution as HTML5 is not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can do this is to use canvas and "save as image", but canvas is not well supported - so if a public website then not recommended. Link: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/

Otherwise you need to do as two separate actions - write the text for display as jQuery, then recreate the image using GD library in PHP. You'll struggle to get them identical, but they can get pretty close.

Comment: I am not looking for HTML5 solution as it is not supported by all browsers... I already have the server side script with imagemagick php to add the text to an image and save as a new image

Comment: In which case you've basically done the work (and the only solution open to you). Have two seaparate actions. That's the system used at http://revealyoursoftside.com/ - you can see the Text written on screen is in Javascript, but the final product (actually a video) is through PHP creating individual images. Sorry, but there's not any other shortcut you can use to "screen grab" the javascript output without canvas. Having said that....

Comment: There is one way we investigated - that's to set up a server running a webbrowser to mimic what's going on on the user's screen, and then using tools on the webserver to screen grab the browser; hopefully this is the same as the user's browser. You can only "copy" one at a time (so you need to queue the requests). We dropped that idea as unfeasable. But that's an option if absolutely required!

Comment: Actually we dont have to copy the screenshot. This is my thinking. We already have some tools for cropping an image using jquery. If we can use the same method to place a text, we can get the x,y corrdinates for that text in that image. Using these coordinates, PHP can write the final output as image

Comment: We are looking for something like a business card editor where users are writing on a predefined templates.

Comment: OK - I understand. I can think of libraries that can do other manipulations through overlays - but they are display-only effects. I just googled again to see if anything was done since I last checked it out (which was October last year for that project above), and they are all HTML5 (Canvas) manipulators. Doesn't mean a solution doesn't exist, but I've done several projects that appear similar and not found a perfect solution. Sorry - no can help more than the advice above!